# How to Play The NsData or CMSampleBuffer that i have in the method?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am sending the nsdata over a UDP socket and want to play this over there so how can I play this? Am I sending the right data to play?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    // Global Scope of Session
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    @IBOutlet weak var recBtn: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func recBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
        session.sessionPreset = .medium
        let mic =  AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
        var mic_input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
        let audio_output = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
        audio_output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        do
        {
            if let temp = mic {
                mic_input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: temp)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return
        }
        if session.inputs.isEmpty {
            session.addInput(mic_input)
            session.addOutput(audio_output)
        }


        session.startRunning()
    }
    @IBAction func StopBtnAction(_ sender: Any){
        session.stopRunning()
    }
   func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        let block = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        var length = 0
        var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>? = nil
        var status = CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(block!, 0, nil, &length, &data)    // TODO: check for errors
       let result = NSData(bytesNoCopy: data!, length: length, freeWhenDone: false)
        print("NSDATA")
         print(result)
    }

}
```

Above is the code which I used to hear the mic data and convert to nsdata and send but I can't play this nsdata so is this right approach to send mic audio data over a socket?